# Date conversion in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, format

I have this part of query that is converting the value of create_date so it can be compared to  the system date.

date_time has a data type of number.

```
NEW_TIME(TO_DATE('1970/01/01 00:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') + (date_time/86400),
        'GMT','CDT')
```

Can someone explain to me the conversion that is happening?
Why is it using the following values like `1970/01/01 00:00:00` and `86400`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Date '1970/01/01 00:00:00' is start date of unix "epoch". Many systems count seconds from this time. Number 86400 is number of seconds in one day. 86400 = 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours

Comment: Niklas how is it set to start from 1970/01/01? Also does this part of the query can cause slow performance? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever or whatever created the numeric value in `date_time` has created it as "seconds since 1st Jan 1970 00:00".

So, the values are based from 1970/01/01.

What you add 1 to a date, you're adding 1 day.  So, the `date_time` value is being divided by the number of seconds in a day.  (60s * 60m * 24h = 86400s)

When you add `Date_Time / 86400` days to the base date, you get the datetime that the value represents

Comment: how is it set to start from 1970/01/01? Also does this part of the query can cause slow performance? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
TO_DATE('1970/01/01 00:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

The data in you column may be in string format  **1970/01/01 00:00:00** and with `to_date`, you tell Oracle to convert it to date format as `yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss` It still shows as **1970/01/01 00:00:00** but it has a **DATE** datatype now. For more informaton about Oracle DATE datatype [look here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847)

And 86400 is a day in terms of seconds: `60 seconds x 60 minutes x 24 hours = 86400`

You use this to add a **new day!**